# Resizing of DialogFragment at runtime

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I am supposed to have a DialogFragment in my app. The purpose of this fragment is to display the zoomed pic if I click on a thumbnail in other fragment.

Here is the layout for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/zoomed_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

So basically, this ImageView is supposed to display the zoomed in pic and I want to display the pic as much as possible on the screen.

I have a bitmap for which I calculate the display size that can fit the screen as much as the screen allows.

**Problem:** The problem is the extra space in the displayed zoomed pic:

*Portrait:*
[image]

*Landscape:*
[image]

I am unable to "crop" this extra space. I read a solution to resizing and I did the following: (before calling `mPhotoView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)` where mPhotoView is the ImageView instance I got from `findViewById()`)

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getArguments().getString(key_imagePath), options);
        float srcWidth = options.outWidth;
        float srcHeight = options.outHeight;

        FrameLayout.LayoutParams p = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams((int)srcWidth, (int)srcHeight);
        view.setLayoutParams(p);
        view.requestLayout();
```

**Question:**

1. How do I remove this extra white space from DialogFragment's view?
2. Does being a DialogFragment mean the layout size is gonna be fixed or there is something like that views in general?
3. Is it possible that it is because of the Layout passes?

Comment: Your Frame Layout XML has `match_parent` try with `wrap_content` to remove white space.

Comment: @MarkKeen : I am trying right now. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkKeen : It's not working with wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

Chanching the first `FrameLayout's` `height` and `width` to "wrap_content" doesn't work? (While setting your `imageView` at a fix sizes as you like.)

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Comment: Then why don't you use a custom layout for your dialog. I use them a lot.

Comment: custom layout...? I didn't get that. Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: Yes, we can use our own custom layout with our own style for dialog. A couple of examples out there.